# Target First Object in Array with Passed MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mongodb

I am using this mongoDB query passed via a POST request to return a subset of data:

```
body: any = {"services.history": { "$elemMatch": { "status": "orientation", "enrolled" : true } }};
```

This is working as expected. However, we're changing our implementation to target a status and a check that it's the first item in the "history" array. How could I accomplish this with a modification of the above query?

I thought this might work, but no go:

```
body: any = {"services.history[0]": { "$elemMatch": { "status": "orientation", "enrolled" : true } }};
```

I also tried dot notation, still no go:

```
body: any = {"services.history.0": { "$elemMatch": { "status": "orientation", "enrolled" : true } }};
```

How can I target just the first item in the array with this kind of query in a POST request? In other words, I only want it to return true if the elemMatch matches AND it's the first item in the "history" array. I only need to run this check on the first object on the `history` array, since I know that'll be the latest (most relevant) data object in the backend array.

The data I'm querying looks like this:

```
  "history": [
                {
                    "status": "oritentation",
                    "endDate": "2012-09-26T06:00:00.000Z",
                    "startDate": "2011-03-26T06:00:00.000Z",
                    "_id": "1259c4d250502sa434788",
                    "enrolled": true,
                }
             ]
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have additional fields inside the subdocuments of your array you can do this:

```
body: any = {"services.history.0": { "status": "orientation", "enrolled" : true } }
```

If you do have additional fields you can do this instead:

```
body: any = { "services.history.0.status": "orientation", "services.history.0.enrolled": true }
```

Comment: I ran both queries using my RoboMongo client and they worked for me... What kind of syntax error are you getting? Which version of MongoDB are you using and what kind of ReST service do you use to access it?

Comment: You're right. It worked! Must have had a typo on my first attempt. Much appreciated, @dnickless.